# Calculating autonomous factor for team members working on a project

Tags: sql

I've a project with several tasks. People work on those tasks and I want to get the "autonomous factor / person" from the below table. This table illustrate what action had been done by whom on every task:

```
    +-------+-------------+------------------+-----------+--------------+
    | Task# | Action Type |       Time       | Action By | Completed By |
    +-------+-------------+------------------+-----------+--------------+
    |     1 | Assigment   | 2015-07-23 10:00 | Nick      | Nick         |
    |     1 | Resolution  | 2015-07-23 10:40 | Nick      | Nick         |
    |     1 | Closure     | 2015-07-23 12:41 | Nick      | Nick         |
    +-------+-------------+------------------+-----------+--------------+
    |     2 | Assigment   | 2015-07-24 10:00 | Nick      | Nick         |
    |     2 | Assigment   | 2015-07-24 10:30 | John      | Nick         |
    |     2 | Resolution  | 2015-07-24 11:30 | Nick      | Nick         |
    |     2 | Closure     | 2015-07-24 12:45 | Nick      | Nick         |
    +-------+-------------+------------------+-----------+--------------+
    |     3 | Assigment   | 2015-07-25 10:00 | John      | Nick         |
    |     3 | Resolution  | 2015-07-25 11:00 | Nick      | Nick         |
    |     3 | Closure     | 2015-07-25 13:50 | Nick      | Nick         |
    +-------+-------------+------------------+-----------+--------------+
    |     4 | Assigment   | 2015-07-26 10:00 | Nick      | Nick         |
    |     4 | Assigment   | 2015-07-26 10:30 | John      | Nick         |
    |     4 | Resolution  | 2015-07-26 10:40 | Nick      | Nick         |
    |     4 | Assigment   | 2015-07-26 11:50 | John      | Nick         |
    |     4 | Closure     | 2015-07-26 14:00 | Nick      | Nick         |
    +-------+-------------+------------------+-----------+--------------+
```

A person is considered autonomous when task come to him, he finish it and close from 1st time.

For example:

1. Task# 1: Nick closed this task and no one touch the task except him
   => Nick is AUTONOMOUS in this task
2. Task# 2: Nick closed this task but it was assigned to someone else (John) before closure => Nick is NOT AUTONOMOUS in this task
3. Task# 3: Nick closed this task and he didn't touch this task before John => Nick is AUTONOMOUS in this task
4. Task# 4: Nick closed this task but someone else (John) worked on before he closed => George is NOT AUTONOMOUS in this task

Hence, Nick autonomous faster is 50% (he worked on and closed 4 tasks but he closed only 2 autonomously). And John autonomous factor is 0% (he didn't close any task).

In summary, Nick considered AUTONOMOUS, if:
 1. Nick is the one closed the task and no one touch it before him (ex: Task# 1),
 2. or if multiple persons worked on the task before Nick but not Nick included, and he is the last one and he closed it (like Task# 3, but not like Task# 2, 4).

**So the question is, is it possible to have a SQL query or simple code that run on above table that can get the autonomous factor/person**, i.e. result expected to be like:

```
+------+-------------------+
| Name | Autonomous Factor |
+------+-------------------+
| Nick | 50%               |
| John | 0%                |
+------+-------------------+
```

Comment: As short answer - it is possible to be done by SQL. What DBMS you will use for this?

Comment: If possible provide a [**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5c2bd/3) That help us to show you a solution.

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov, whatever is the DBMS, I could use MySQL, sqlite, or even Microsoft Access?

Comment: I ask because in some DBMS you can use specific keywords to make query more simple. In general answer of @Gordon Linoff seems ok. I myself will try to group and see if each task have only one user and is closed. I am not sure if it is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like an aggregation of an aggregation.  I think the "autonomous" logic is simply that no one touches the task between the time someone closed it and the first time that person saw the task.  This can be expressed by these rules:

- The maximum time for anyone else on the task is less than the minimum time for the person
- The maximum time for the person on the task is the same as the maximum time for the task closure.

To gather this information you need to consider each person assigned to the task.  That requires a `cross join` between the people on the task and the task data.

The resulting query:

```
select t.task, p.person,
       (case when min(t.actionby) = max(t.actionby) then 1
             when (max(case when t.actionby <> p.person then time end) >
                   min(case when t.actionby = p.person then time end)
                  ) and
                  (max(case when t.actionby = p.person then time end) =
                   max(case when t.action = 'Closure' then time end)
                  )
             then  1 else 0
        end) as IsAutonomous
from (select distinct task, actionby as person from tasks) p join
     tasks t
     on p.task = t.task
group by t.task, p.person;
```

Once you have this information, the rest is just an additional aggregation:

```
select person, avg(IsAutonomous)
from (select t.task, p.person,
             (case when min(t.actionby) = max(t.actionby) then 1
                       (max(case when t.actionby <> p.person then time end) >
                         min(case when t.actionby = p.person then time end)
                        ) and
                        (max(case when t.actionby = p.person then time end) =
                         max(case when t.action = 'Closure' then time end)
                        )
                   then  1 else 0
              end) as IsAutonomous
      from (select distinct task, actionby as person from tasks) p join
           tasks t
           on p.task = t.task
      group by t.task, p.person
     ) tp
group by person;
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon, I didn't thought the question will be answered in 20 minutes :) . I'm trying this but this syntax related to specific DBMS?

Comment: @RamiSedhom . . . It turns out this is ANSI standard syntax, so it should work in pretty much any database.  I did take liberties with the table and column names.

Comment: I'm trying on MySQL. Got error:  

` #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'then t.actionby = p.person then time end) =
                   max(case then t.a' at line 5`

Still trying ...

Comment: it worked perfectly after minor syntax correction in line 5 and 6. I've edited your answer to reflect the correct syntax.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Here is the [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6c319/2) hope that help. I didn't continue because saw was already solve. But right now the solution return double 0, instead of (50%,0)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . Thank you for the SQL Fiddle.  However, it had an error.  The `time` needs to be `datetime`, rather than `date` (and there was a bug in my query).  Here is a working SQL Fiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/34cfe/2.